# Trying to add scanning utilities to a Docker image

Tags: docker, docker-compose

For a scanner front-end project I am trying to add sane, sane-utils and a proprietary package (brscan4 from Brother) to an existing docker image but with no luck. The original file is located [here](https://github.com/api-platform/api-platform/blob/master/api/Dockerfile).
One limitation I have is that the original Dockerfile uses Alpine but I need a driver to talk to my scanner (Brother's) and this driver only exists for Arch and Debian / Ubuntu.

Here are the changes I tried so far:

```
FROM php:${PHP_VERSION}-fpm-alpine AS api_platform_php
# Add required packages
# edge/testing required for sane-utils
RUN echo "http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing/" >> /etc/apk/repositories && \
   apk add --update --no-cache sane sane-utils
```

This was added at the top of the file. It actually works and the binaries are available but trying to add the scanner package won't work (debian only).

I also tried the following, using pure debian packages (added at the end of the Dockerfile):

```
FROM debian:stretch-slim
RUN apt update && apt install -y \
    sane \
    sane-utils \
    wget \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && wget http://www.brother.com/pub/bsc/linux/dlf/brscan4-0.4.2-1.amd64.deb && dpkg -i brscan4-0.4.2-1.amd64.deb
```

Running docker-compose up --build works, but the binaries are nowhere to be found.

Are there any error in my approach or is this a no-go ?

Comment: Add also the content of your docker-compose file.

Comment: No longer have it, but the modified version is visible [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51831867/sane-utils-binaries-core-dump-in-docker)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally decided to create a completely new instance based on stretch-slim and retrieve all the required binaries that way. Guess the issue was because the docker-compose.yml referenced an alpine image but the Dockerfile tried to install packages from debian:stretch-slim.